# What is a more reliable way to scan for user commands that will run administrative commands on a user system?

Tags: security, powershell, automation, windows-task-scheduler, windows-domain

On an AD domain, with a Windows 10 "deployment server" and 50 other Windows 10 hosts, I want to add a way for users to make LOCAL GPO changes by issuing a command. Each user has their own needs and needs to change them as desired (with a few minutes latency).

There are only really janky ways to do this so far.

Like run task scheduler on the deployment server every minute to go visit a user-accessible place on their workstation, the task is a powershell script that inspects the file names aka the commands.
e.g. if one of the files is named "Potato" then powershell will make fully predefined GPO changes to that host.

When doing that though, SYSTEM on the deployment server doesn't have domain/localadmin access to the user's system. So you have to set a high-risk GPO for the deployment server (Network access: Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication Disabled) that will allow you to save a domain admin's creds to the task so that it can run even while that admin is not logged in.

So I have three problems in this scheme:

1. You should not disable the "Not allow storage of passwords"
2. The powershell script will take a long time to make its rounds to many hosts. Not entirely reliable I think.
3. If the deployment server is busy with other things, the minutely task will work a lot less reliably even then.

Are there any non-janky ways to give the user the ability to issue a "command" that will be picked up by a deployment server and the command then executed, elevated on the user's system (without the user having any special permissions at all)?
"A parameterized request for admin-elevated tasks"

Comment: So if you are not forcing domain replication once a GPO change is made, and then ensuring gpupdate is run on the client, it will likely stay janky. The scheduled task as you talk about should work without those elevated permissions you talk about post domain replicate and then also gpupdate from the client once domain controller replication occurs from the site the user account or computer account object resides but with a restart of the computer. Force AD replication from a DC with `repadmin /syncall /AdeP` then `gpupdate /force` from the client, then reboot to test janky solution.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle The thing is tho, that each user may throughout the day need to change the GPOs (or other admin-only system changes) multiple times a day. gpupdate isn't a thing because we're applying local GPOs (this is for host-only GPOs). Ill update the question

Comment: I'm not sure why on the deployment server the job cannot run from there with `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { <your commands> } -AsJob -Credential (Get-Credential);` and never having any stored credential accessible to the non-admin end user. You would define the credential on the deployment server, and it would invoke the command with that credential on the server.

Comment: You've already worked the magic logic out changing the local GPOs programmatically and now is just the trivial stuff. If it's all 'local' though, `SYSTEM` context should get it alone, just put what's needed locally then execute it via task scheduler. The trick there is to make it not dependent on network access from the local execution for it to complete. I assume it's just code but I understand large file copy dependency type of situations though with network constraints, etc. Execute the checking trigger logic with the network accessible cred, then invoke it locally logic wise, etc.

Comment: With `Invoke-command` maybe you can work it out using explicit local account credentials from the deployment server. If you have issues, drop a local scripted PowerShell logic, then execute that local file with the invoke-command within the scriptblock part of it. Good luck!